# Impresion de ticket con JS o jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo un sistema de consultas el cual imprime un voucher con un numero de consulta y cierta información adicional, todo esto esta hecho con asp.net mvc 5 había usado PrintDocument() para imprimir en las impresoras térmicas de mis clientes pero al parecer la opción de hacer la impresión desde el lado del servidor no es la adecuada para poder imprimir hacia mis clientes.

Por ello decidi manejar la impresión del voucher mediante JS o jQuery pero como puedo imprimir un voucher con este lenguaje? existen librerías para ello? y la pregunta del millón... como puedo eliminar el cuadro de dialogo al imprimir con javascript u que me imprima directamente sobre la impresora predeterminada?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar simplemente la función `window.print()`

Ejemplo en jQuery:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#print").click(function() {
        window.print();
    });
});
</script>

<a id='print'>Imprimir</a>
```

Ejemplo en JavaScript:

```
<script>
function printMe() {
    window.print()
}
</script>
<input type="button" value="Imprimir" onclick="printMe()">
```

Obtenido de [los compañeros de ingleses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16724550/sending-data-to-printer).

Comment: Pero eso me levanta la ventana de impresión o el asistente. Necesito que no me levante la ventana de dialogo de la impresión...

Comment: JavaScript no puede enviar datos directamente a la impresora. Sería una vulnerabilidad.

Comment: En todo caso, en las fuente que he añadido explica que sería necesario un plugin en el navegador de cada cliente.

Comment: No entiendo el voto negativo en todo caso

Comment: Por que en la pregunta indico claramente que no me debe levantar el cuadro de dialogo...

Comment: ¿Y decir que no se puede y mostrarte una aproximación no es respuesta a eso?